# Determine the Plurality of a Noun/Verb

Tags: java, nlp, cpu-word

I have a program that is randomly generating sentences based on a bunch of text documents of all the nouns, verbs, adjectives, and adverbs. Does anyone know a way to determine if a noun/verb are plural or singular, or if there any text documents that contain a list of singular nouns/verbs and plural nouns? I'm doing this all in Java, and I have a decent idea of how to get information off of a website, so if there are any websites that could do that as well, I'd also appreciate those.

Comment: You could use the Stanford NLP part-of-speech tagger, which is written in Java, though that may be overkill for your use case: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.html

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, you cannot solve this by having a fixed list of words, especially verbs. Consider sentences:

> You are free. We are free.

In the first one, *are* is singular, it is plural. Using a proper tagger as @jdaz suggests is the only way how you can do it in a reliable way.

If you work with English or a few other supported languages, [StanfordNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP) is an excellent choice. If you need a broad language coverage, you can use [UDPipe](http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/udpipe) that is natively in C++ but has a Java binding.

Comment: If you check the word before the verb you'd be able to disambiguate this. That's essentially what a tagger does as well.

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to look it up in a list. For English you can reduce the size of the list by only including singular nouns, and then apply some basic string processing to find plurals: if your word ends in *-s* and is not in the list, cut off the *-s* and look again. If it now is in the list, it was a simple plural (*car*/*cars*). If not, continue. If it ends in *-ies*, remove that, append *-y* and look again. Now you will capture *remedies*/*remedy*. There are a number of such patterns you can use.

Some irregular nouns need to be in an exception list (*ox*/*oxen*), but there aren't that many. Some words of course are unspecified, like *sheep*, *data*, or *police*. Here you need to look at the context: if the noun is followed by a singular verb (eg *eats*, or *is*), then it would be singular as well.

With (English) verbs you can generally only identify the third person singular (with a similar procedure as used for nouns; you's need a list of exceptions for verbs anding in *-s* (such as *kiss*)). Forms of *to be* are more helpful, but the second person singular is an issue (*are*). However, unless you have direct speech in your texts, it will not be used very frequently.

Part of speech taggers can also only make these decisions on context, so I don't think they will be much of a help here. It's likely to be overkill. A couple of word lists and simple heuristic rules will probably give you equal or better accuracy using far fewer resources. This is the way these things were done before large amounts of annotated data were available.

In the end it depends on your circumstances. It might be quicker to simply use an existing tagger, but *for this limited problem* you might get better accuracy and speed with the rule-based approach, (or even a combined one for accuracy).